# File Upload in NodeJs with express-fileupload not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, for-loop

I have made a REST API in NodeJs for File Upload working okay but there is an Issue, if i upload more then 2 images only 2, 3 get uploads and sometimes 1 gets corrupted. i think my Loop is running too fast for this. 
blow is my Code:

```
app.post('/img-upload', function(req, res) {
  if (!req.files)
    return res.status(400).send({"status":"false", "data":"Image Not Found"});

  // Use the mv() method to place the file somewhere on your server
    for(var key in req.files) {

        thisFile = req.files[key];
        let name = +new Date();
        thisFile.mv('./images/' + name++ +'.png', function(err) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            }   

        });

    }
        res.json({"status":"File uploaded!"});
});
```

module used: `express-fileupload`

Comment: `res.json()` might be causing the request to close before the file uploads finish. You have to wait until each of the callbacks have completed.

Comment: can you explain More!

Comment: It's possible that two files are being moved to the same destination path. Like you said, the loop flies pretty quickly. Calls to `new Date()` will most likely return same value for two iterations. One solution is to move the counter variable `name` outside of the loop body.

Answer (score 4):

Posting an answer that may not be *the* answer, to explain the comment by @PatrickRoberts who seems to have a point.

`thisFile.mv` apparently works asynchronously, meaning `function(err){...}` might be run *after* `res.json(...)` and the following implicit `return`.

Although Node shouldn't kill the remaining async processes, you're anyway too early to tell the user that files were uploaded successfully. (You could send that success, *then* one of your callbacks throws an error... but too late, you can't send that error to the client.)

Two options to see this through.

#### a decent option

Wait for all callbacks to be completed to send a successful result. Probably something like:

```
let uploads = [];
for (let k in req.files) {
  req.files[k].mv('/my/path/to.png', function(err) {
    let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve();
      }
    });
    uploads.push(promise);

  })
} // end for loop
Promise.all(uploads).then(function() {
  res.json({"status":"File uploaded!"});
}).catch(function(err) {
  res.send(err);
});
```

#### a slow option that I'm ashamed of

In case this doesn't fix it, and assuming @PatrickRoberts spotted the correct issue, you can try and make the uploads sequentially, like:

```
function processFile() {
  let file = req.files.shift()
  if (!file) return; // stop sequence condition
  file.mv('/my/path/to.png', function(err) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      processFile();
    }
  })
}
processFile(); // start the recursive and sequential "loop"
```

If none of these work (the second, bad option is slow but a clear proof of whether `res.json`/`res.send` are involved), then your issue lies elsewhere. In such a case, please give more information about "sometimes one is corrupted": is the file incomplete? Is it the server showing an error? The client receiving an error? In the latter cases, what error?

Comment: i have tried everything.. as you said, stop sending response before all files. i discussed it with my PHP friend he said your loop is running too fast to handle more files, they use `sleep()` to slow down their loops.  "sometimes one is corrupted" : This means if i send 5 files 2 uploads normally 3rd gets uploaded but not opens it says file is corrupt and remaining 2 are lost....

Comment: Have you tried implemented the second, fail-safe method I proposed? Also, this might be related to a network issue: try uploading only light, 1kB files?

Comment: I tried your method but no luck. single files is uploading fine. 2 or more files causing issues...

Comment: What do you use to implement the `req.files` property and the `file.mv` method?

Comment: `express-fileupload`

Comment: I just tried locally with your setup on an Ubuntu 16, no error. I'm going to edit my answer with that code so you can check the diff.

Comment: Oh actually I re-read your post and comments: your files are not corrupted/lost, they most probably override each other... which achieve the same result.
In your code, instead of naming the files using `+new Date()`, give them a unique number (use a counter or something). If I understand your problem, it's because the date can be the same across several iterations of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

this work for me

```
 let media = req.files; 

 for (let pos in media) {
   media[pos].mv(`./media/${renameFile}`, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                ok: false,
                err
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have installed express-fileUpload again do it with this command
if you want to upload image kindly give name attribute (case sensitive ) and try

`npm install express body-parser cors express-fileupload morgan lodash --save`

for me it worked ...

Comment: ye morgan and lodash?